# C# Multithreading - Performance Issue

Tags: c#, multithreading, threadpool

I have console application with numerical calculation, which I am trying to parallel using the ThreadPool.

I got object state as class (simple-data-passing):

```
public class DataContainer
{
    public double[,] Exa;
    public double[] EQ;
    public int iStart;
    public int iEnd;
}
```

Definition for WaitCallback

```
private  void Calculate(object state)
{
    DataContainer data = state as DataContainer;

    for (int m = data.iStart; m < data.iEnd; m++)
    {
        double temp= 0.0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 500000; i++)
        {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < 500000; j++)
            {
                //Some-Long-Calculation based on data.Exa-around 200 math operation with results of double EQC
                if (EQC> temp) { temp= EQC; } //line performance issue-temp is declared in first for-loop block;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Execution:

```
WaitCallback waitCallback = Calculate;
const int numberOfThreads = 100;
ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(30, 100);
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfThreads; i++)
{
    DataContainer tempContainer = new DataContainer();
    tempContainer.Exa = Exa; 
    tempContainer.EQ = EQ;
    tempContainer.iStart = CalculateStart(i);
    tempContainer.iEnd = CalculateEnd(i);

    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(waitCallback, tempContainer);
}

int numberOfTotalThreads = 0;
int numberOfMaxThreads = 0;
int numberOfWorkingThreads = 0;
int temp = 0;
//do-while - waiting to finish all calculation 
do
{
    ThreadPool.GetAvailableThreads(out numberOfTotalThreads, out temp);
    ThreadPool.GetMaxThreads(out numberOfMaxThreads, out temp);
    numberOfWorkingThreads = numberOfMaxThreads - numberOfTotalThreads;
    Console.WriteLine("Number of working threads {0}", numberOfWorkingThreads);
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
} while (numberOfWorkingThreads > 0);
```

So one marked line:

```
if (EQC> temp) { temp= EQC; }
```

Time exeuction of program slow down from 40s to 600s.

Could you advice how these line should be written to avoid that problem?

Comment: `const int numberOfThreads = 100;` - why is this a thing when you're querying `ThreadPool.GetMaxThreads()` ?

Comment: How many cores you have and how many threads per core?? If your program only has access to one core/thread then thread pool will do nothing but harm in this case.

Comment: without these line that I pointed it is speed around 4x time, because I got 2-core processor with two threads per core - so one line causes problem

Comment: Dai, yes you are right, querying these MaxThreads is not necessary.

Comment: Do you mean that when you omit calculation result and not assigning to "temp" variable, it works much faster? If yes, then probably compiler just throw away some part of calculations knowing result it not used.

Comment: dlxeon could you explain more? So if I calculate something in the loop and not used final double anywhere compiler will not do these calculations inside that loop?

Comment: @Kaspar - In almost all occasions when you call `Thread.Sleep` you are probably doing something wrong.

Comment: This is a terrible way to check when you're done. How do you know something else in your code hasn't grabbed a thread from the pool and just hung on to it?

Comment: Why not use TPL, Parallel, or Rx? All of which are designed to do this kind of work for you. If you could provide a [mcve] I'd be happy to show you how.